# regex wrap strings in quotes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have an array like the example below but much much bigger (4000 lines long):

```
array(
   "id" => array(
        "a" => "", 
        "b" => "", 
        "c" => Needs Quotes Around Me
), "id" => array(
        "a" => "", 
        "b" => "", 
        "c" => Needs Quotes Around Me
        "d" => Needs Quotes Around Me
)
);
```

The string values for some reason dont have the quotes ("") around them and the colon seperator. Some of the strings are numbers but can be treated as a string and some have spaces and the @ symbols as some are email addresses but I need to wrap all of them in `"STRING HERE",`

Im trying to use reg_replace with something like this `=>\s([a-zA-Z0-9\@\s])+$` but it doesnt replace the matched string with the string it found?  Ive done quite a bit of googling but cant seem to get it right, please tell me where Im going wrong.

What I end up with is:

```
array(
       "id" => array(
            "a" => "", 
            "b" => "", 
            "c" => "[a-zA-Z0-9\@\s]",
    ), "id" => array(
            "a" => "", 
            "b" => "", 
            "c" => "[a-zA-Z0-9\@\s]",
            "d" => "[a-zA-Z0-9\@\s]",
    )
);
```

Comment: Provide some code that you've tried and we'll try to help you out.

Comment: Have you tried using double slashes? i.e. `\\s` instead of `\s`?

Comment: anubhava your comment is very unhelpful.  I said the array is 4000+ lines long it would be ridiculous to post the array and the preg _replace here.  Ive given the regex ive tried which didnt work. We have since managed to solve this issue which was as simple as putting circular brackets around the expression but its only easy if you know that.  In future if you have nothing constuctive to say dont bother.

Comment: If you solved the problem, please add the solution as an answer. After one day you may then accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It required placing circular brackets around the regex.  As simple as this sounds its only easy when you know how.

Answer (score 1):

This perl script works for the example given

```
perl -pe 's/(?<==> )(?!"|array\()(.*)/"$1",/' EXAMPLEFILE.txt
```

the following output is produced:

```
array(
   "id" => array(
        "a" => "", 
        "b" => "", 
        "c" => "Needs Quotes Around Me",
), "id" => array(
        "a" => "", 
        "b" => "", 
        "c" => "Needs Quotes Around Me",
        "d" => "Needs Quotes Around Me",
)
);
```